# Java Do while loop not working when I need it

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Why does my output1 not print out like the corrected output1?  When the numbers come in ascending order program works fine.  When they dont as you can see it does no.  Please help, I can use a do while or while loop.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    int entry;
    int entry2;
    int entry3;

    System.out.println("Enter three integers");
    System.out.println("Side 1: ");
    entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Side 2: ");
    entry2 = keyboard.nextInt();

    do {

        entry3 = 0;

        if (entry2 <= entry) {

            System.out.println(entry2 + " is smaller than " + entry + " Try again.");
            System.out.println("Side 2");
            entry2 = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        else if (entry2 > entry) {
            System.out.println("Side 3: ");
            entry3 = keyboard.nextInt();

        }  if (entry3 <= entry2) {
            System.out.println("\nYour three sides are " + entry + " " + entry2 + " " + entry3);
            System.out.println("NO!  These sides do not make a right triangle!");
        } if (entry3 > entry2) {
            System.out.println("\nYour three sides are " + entry + " " + entry2 + " " + entry3);
            System.out.println("These sides *do* make a right triangle.  Yippy-skippy!");

        }

    } while (entry2 < entry);

}

}
```

My Output: 1

```
Enter three integers
Side 1: 
2
Side 2: 
1
1 is smaller than 2 Try again.
Side 2
2
```

My Output 2:

```
Enter three integers
Side 1: 
1
Side 2: 
2
Side 3: 
3

Your three sides are 1 2 3
These sides *do* make a right triangle.  Yippy-skippy!
```

Correct output for Output1:

```
Enter three integers:
Side 1: 4
Side 2: 3
3 is smaller than 4.  Try again.
Side 2: -9
-9 is smaller than 4.  Try again.
Side 2: 5
Side 3: 1
1 is smaller than 5.  Try again.
Side 3: 5

Your three sides are 4 5 5
NO!  These sides do not make a right triangle!
```

Comment: Explain what your programs needs to do. Tell us your requirements. Showing a not working program without telling what you are expecting is a non solvable question for other people.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry I want the program to allow the user to enter three integers. I want to enforce  that these integers are in ascending order and duplicate numbers are allowed.

and I want to tell the user whether or not these integers would represent the sides of a right triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your approach conditions for checking whether a triangle is right or not, it is totally wrong. If you are checking the lengths of the 3 sides, then it should be as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class App1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    int entry;
    int entry2;
    int entry3;
    boolean check = true;

    while(check) {
    System.out.println("Enter three integers");
    System.out.println("Side 1: ");
    entry = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Side 2: ");
    entry2 = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Side 3: ");
    entry3 = keyboard.nextInt();

    int a = entry*entry;
    int b = entry1*entry1;
    int c = entry2*entry2;

    if((a == b + c) || (b == a + c ) || (c == a + b) {
        System.out.println("The Triangle is right.");
        check = false;
    }

    else
    System.out.println("The Triangle is not right. Please try Again!!!");    
    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
int entry;
int entry2;
int entry3;

System.out.println("Enter three integers");
System.out.println("Side 1: ");
entry = keyboard.nextInt();
System.out.println("Side 2: ");
entry2 = keyboard.nextInt();

while(entry2 <= entry) {
   System.out.println(entry2 + " is smaller than " + entry + " Try again.");
   System.out.println("Side 2");
   entry2 = keyboard.nextInt();
}
//Execution reaches beyond this point only when entry2>entry
System.out.println("Side 3: ");
entry3 = keyboard.nextInt();

if (entry3 <= entry2) {
  System.out.println("\nYour three sides are " + entry + " " + entry2 + " " + entry3);

  System.out.println("NO!  These sides do not make a right triangle!");
}
if (entry3 > entry2) {
  System.out.println("\nYour three sides are " + entry + " " + entry2 + " " + entry3);
  System.out.println("These sides *do* make a right triangle.  Yippy-skippy!");
}
```